# Firebase Auth stateListener necessary?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my iPhone app's home screen I need to check whether the user is logged in or not. In my `viewDidAppear()` I check like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
       // user is logged in
   } else {
       // user not logged in, send to home page
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NotLoggedInSegue", sender: self)
   }
}
```

In every example online I see people using `FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener` in their code. If my app's only authentication is through gmail, do I need that or is the way I'm checking if the user is logged in fine?

Comment: The user may not yet be logged in when your view appears. In that case your current code will miss it.

Comment: But in my Login Page I log the user in using `FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error)` and only if the `user` isn't `nil` then I segue to this page. Wouldn't that mean the user would have to be logged in at that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you wrote is correct but it will be called only when view did method is called hence suppose after viewDidAppear the auth token expires and user on that screen is accessing few values from FIRAuth.auth.currentuser, which will return nil

Despite of that the FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() is called whenever there is state change in auth.

```
handle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

Comment: My problem with using the adding ` FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener()` in the `viewDidAppear()` is that every time the page loads a new state listener is added when I only need 1 state listener.

Comment: detach the listener in the view controller's viewWillDisappear method: FIRAuth.auth()?.removeStateDidChangeListener(handle!)  also you can have a baseviewcontroller for all controllers